# Why do I get an error message tells me that Pi Camera is not enabled even though it is?

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspi-config

I'm trying to run some code and it works with the Pi Camera and the Lepton FLIR camera, but the problem is that when I try to run the code I get a bunch of error messages ending with a line that says:

`Camera is not enabled. Try running sudo raspi-config`

I did that and enabled the camera and then rebooted, but I continue to get the same error message. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the picamera module connected correctly to the RPI?

Comment: Yes, it will only go in one way so I'm sure.

Comment: have you installed picamera for Python version you are using?

Comment: You should try `raspistill` quickly and see if that works, or if it says the same thing.  Beware the cable attachment may be finicky, you have to bury the silver lines on the correct side at both ends.

Comment: I ran `raspistill` and it didn't give me an error message. It just showed me a bunch of documentation.

Comment: @OsamaAbbas What do you mean?

Comment: I meant as in try to take a picture with it.  You may have to follow the documentation ;)  (`raspistill -o test.jpg` should do it; either you'll get no message (or at least nothing unduly negative, I can't remember) and a `test.jpg` will be left behind, or else a message from "mmal" that there's no camera).

Comment: @goldilocks Ya I got an error message. Do you think I should disconnect the camera and reconnect it?

Comment: You could try.  If that doesn't work leave another comment and I'll check exactly what it is `raspi-config` is *supposed* to have done.  **Note you probably must reboot after running it** for the changes to take effect, so if you didn't do that, make sure to do so now and try again.

Comment: WRT to the cable, the printed side with the silver stripes should be facing the same direction as the camera on that side, and toward the ethernet jack on the pi side.

Comment: The cable only goes in one way so I'm pretty sure that I plugged it in correctly. I rebooted but the `raspistill` is still giving me the same error. Do you think that for some reason my enabling of the camera isn't sticking after the reboot?

Comment: Have you installed picamera library already? If not type the following `sudo pip install python-picamera`

Comment: The cable can go in either way; the correct orientation is with the blue side of the ribbon facing the Ethernet port (or the USB port if it's a model A+). There's some [pictures of a correctly installed cable](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/quickstart.html) in the getting started chapter of the docs. If this is a V1 module does the LED come on when you run `raspistill -o test.jpg`? (unfortunately the V2 module lacks a LED, so it's a bit harder to debug)

Answer (score 0):

All `raspi-config` does is add a few lines to `/boot/config.txt`:

```
start_x=1
gpu_mem=128
```

Apparently the latter (128 MB) is the minimum required, and you will get a specific (memory related) error about that otherwise.  This comes out of your available RAM.

So:

- Check if those are there and not commented out with `#`, or superseded by other `gpu_mem` (there are a few forms of that, suffixed with with a number, e.g., `gpu_mem_1024` -- there should only be one) or `start_x` values in the file.
- Make sure you've rebooted since they were added.
- Make sure your firmware and kernel are reasonably up to date:

  ```
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt upgrade
  ```

  Will do it although it will update everything else at the same time, which you might as well do (I'm not sure what the exact package is).  If you've *never* done that, you should have post install and it may take a few minutes.  Alternately, you could use `rpi-update` (`sudo apt install rpi-upate`, then `sudo rpi-update`) to pull just the kernel, modules, and firmware but beware this puts you ahead of the Raspbian default and may be a minor gamble.  It's never caused me any grief, but the former method (update the system completely via apt `update` then `upgrade`) is preferrable.  **You'll have to reboot after this** too regardless of which technique you use.

If all that is done and the camera is properly connected, but `raspistill` doesn't work, something is busted.

Comment: I did the second two things you've listed, but I didn't fully understand what you mean. I ran `nano /boot/config.txt` and found the two lines you mentioned. They're not commented out but other lines in the file are commented out. Is that okay? I didn't fully understand what you were trying to say.

Comment: There's lots of stuff in that file that's commented out (including the actual comments), that's fine.  But those lines should not be and should be what's shown above (`gpu_mem` could be higher but not lower).  By "superseded" I meant make sure the lines are not listed (uncommented) more than once, and that you should beware of the fact that `gpu_mem` has a couple of other potential forms:  https://github.com/raspberrypi/documentation/blob/master/configuration/config-txt.md#gpu_mem

Comment: If you haven't messed with that file or installed software that does, this should all be in order, just it does not hurt to double check if something isn't working right.  An easy way to do that is `grep start_x /boot/config.txt` and `grep gpu_mem /boot/config.txt`.  Remember, if it's part of a comment or commented out it doesn't matter.  If all that's done and you are using a current kernel and firmware, `raspistill` should work.